# Protecting my JSON-based level configuration data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game in Swift with SpriteKit that I envision to have (for now) about 100 levels. They're broken out into areas (20 levels per area). Most areas are free, but I'd like to make one or two very special areas that require some hard work to get the ability to play. Maybe i'll even make one require a purchase if it's worth it.

So to make things easy, I just made all the levels as JSON configuration files when needed, and my reader will pull the settings and hydrate the level class from that. Thus I have 100 level files.

I was thinking about this, and realized that there isn't anything stopping an attacker from using a tool like ifunbox to browse to the JSON files, find the premium ones, take the contents, overwrite the non-premium ones, and then play the premium content for free.

Should I keep the JSON files and just encrypt them? I was thinking another alternative would be to keep level hashes of each level and do a comparison, but that would require 100 hashes in my code file.

Could someone offer me a suggestion as to protect my level configuration data a little better so premium content stays premium?

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with keeping hashes for all levels. You can keep hashes in another file and keep a hash for it, if you don't want to keep them in code file.

Comment: Can an attacker gain access to the hashes though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use apples [On Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/) so that the files arent actually in the app to begin with, and it will only download the premium maps once the purchase has been made

> **Benefits of On-Demand Resources**
>
> Some of the main ways apps can benefit from on-demand resources
> include:
>
> **Smaller app size.** The size of the app bundle downloaded by the user is
> smaller resulting in faster downloads and more storage room on the
> device.
>
> **Lazy loading of app resources.** The app has resources that are
> used only in certain states. The resources are requested when the app
> is likely to enter the appropriate state. For example, in a game with
> many levels, the user needs only the resources associated with the
> current and next levels.
>
> **Remote storage of rarely used resources.** The
> app has resources that are used infrequently. The resources are
> requested as they are needed. For example, an app tutorial is usually
> shown once after the app is opened for the first time, and may never
> be used again. The app requests the tutorial on first launch, and then
> requests the tutorial only when needed or when new features are added.
>
> **Remote storage of in-app purchase resources.** The app offers in-app
> purchases that includes additional resources. The resources for
> purchased modules are requested by the app after it is launched. For
> example, a user purchases the SuperGeeky emoticon pack in a keyboard
> app. The app requests the pack after it finishes launching.

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks. Otherwise, is there an alternative for example encryption or hashing?

Comment: the problem with those is it just shifts the problem, if you maps are encrypted or hashed, if they decompile your app they will be able to find the encryption key or the hash in your code

Comment: Thanks this is precisely what I was curious about - is it feasible to decompile and look at some or all of the source code, thus gaining access to my key or list of hashes? Then they could publish this on the web in theory and everyone would access it. Another thing is what if someone (one person) buys the level, and then shares it. Then someone else could just edit the first JSON file for level 1, replacing level 1 with level 100 (premium). I feel like I need some kind of checksum..

Comment: yep theoretically, this security stuff is a difficult problem to solve :P but ye if you did the encryption route, hopefully the key would be different on a per app basis somehow, so if someone found the key they wouldnt be able to unlock it for everyone by sharing it, but that may be difficult to achieve on its own. simplest would be the on demand resources, dont even let them have the file until its purchased

Comment: What do you think about just using KeyChain?

Comment: i dont have any experience with using it so im not sure, but probably a viable option as well

Comment: 1.The Keychain is the most secure way to save small data such as keys. 2. On iOS it is not possible to decompile the binary files, they are encrypted with an Apple certificate. In order to access the binary files an attacker needs to jailbreak the iOS device and install debugging software to catch the binary file in memory after the binary launches. It is doable but beyond casual attackers.

Comment: Thanks Zaph. For keys i'll use keychain. For Level Configuration data (big things) should I encrypt the files and decrypt them with a key stored in my binary (in a .swift file let's say) or should I use on-demand resources? My fear is someone can just edit the non-premium file, replacing it with premium content, whereas if it were encrypted (or I used a hash to prevent tampering) it would ensure authenticity